# Display text in new line - HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display formatted text on HTML, text string is coming from database. Text is displayed in a `<div class="col-xs-12">` and inside div i have `<pre>` tag.

If the text size is more than screen it goes out of the div width as displayed in screeen shot. I would like to break line if there is no more width and start a new line to display remaining text. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: pre{white-space:normal;}

Answer (score 1):

Add following css in your styles:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```css
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<pre>Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... Long text here... </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add:

```
pre {
   white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla */
   white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
   word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer */
}
```

to your css.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `<pre>` use paragraph tag `<p> some text </p>` or use `<p> <pre> some text </pre></p>`

**in css**

```
p{
   white-space: pre-wrap;    
   word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CSS:

```
pre{
  display:block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```